# How to store the encrypted data in numeric data field?

Tags: sql, encryption

I want to encrypt some data in .net before i store them in sql server 2008 database. but this issue is that the field type is numeric

is there any algorithm which can give me numeric values only upon encryption

Comment: how long is this numeric field? 1 bit 2, 4, 8 ?

Comment: Is the source data also int? Does it have to be reversible?

Comment: @gbn yes, source data is also int

Comment: @marc_s, I have to write a .Net fx

Comment: @Aakash: yes, I understand - but that does it **look like** ?? What parameters does it take in, what does it return??

Answer (score 0):

If you have Enterprise Edition you can use [Transparent Data Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx)

Comment: I have workgroup edition that doesn't support TDE. Thats why i have to do it at .Net level.

Answer (score -5):

Define your own encryption method. using + - / * operators. Think about decryption method also when you implementing encryption method.

Comment: This is obfuscation, not encryption

Comment: OK. how it could be easy to crack ? Dont tell your encryp. method to your friends. :P